# CSS Test with Capybara and rails

Tags: css, ruby, rspec, capybara

I'm trying to find out how to test for the number of page elements that are on a particular view by counting the instances of the class I find. I'm running rails 4.0.0, Ruby 2.0.0, and Capybara 2.0.1.

Here's my test:

```
it "has 10 successful charges" do
  visit '/'
  expect(page).to have_css("ul.successful", :count => 10)
end
```

Which is outputting:

```
Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_css("ul.successful", :count => 10)
   expected #has_css?("ul.successful", {:count=>10}) to return true, got false
```

When I run rspec spec, my other tests in the same file are working as expected, so that's not the issue.

Comment: have you tried save_and_open_page to visually inspect the code and seen if there is indeed 10 x ul.successful there?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
page.all("ul.successful").length.should == 10
```

`page.all` returns an array of results, which you can count using the `.length` suffix. Rspec should give you an error and a helpful explanation if it doesn't find exactly 10 results. For example:

```
RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError: expected: 10
got: 9 (using ==)
```